# Custom view or fragment for a file manager?

Tags: android, view, fragment

- I searched but didnt find a way to mach my needs.

What are differences between a custom view and a fragment?
I think they both turn out as a view!
What if I use custom view as a component to list my local files for each tab of my file manager?
Would it be a standard way?

I made it but I doubt if custom view will use more memory space or cpu usage against fragments? And if it will be cross-device?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: yeah....custom views takes more resources compared to other views.

Comment: Compare to fragments???

Comment: ha.....compared to fragments or if you take any other view. The reason for this is simple. You are drawing your custom view using canvas and that to using paint, drawables, (optionally surface view) etc.

Comment: But also fragments are drawn as a custom view

Comment: A custom View and a Fragment are totally different things. Fragment does not extend View.

Comment: Your named fragment will be a custome view with the name of your fragment

Answer (score 0):

fragment its look like activity if we create an app on fragment that comfortable for bath mobile and tablet [Fragment](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Coustem View its part of or view in android like

`TextView`, 
`Buttan`,
`ImageView`,
`ImageButtan`,

By the help of create view is called `Coustem View`

Touchimageview is called Coustem View in android [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

Comment: I know but it sounds it will turn out as a custom view with some more events? Aint it?

Comment: I wanna use custom view instead of fragment in my app because i think controlling over it is much easier